# Print #number of array with FOREACH Instead FOR

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

i have array and i want print #5 of array

i write this with `FOR` but not work currently

this is my code and i want to get result with `FOREACH`

```
$tagsfinal =Array
(
[0] =say
[1] =hello
[2] =nice
[3] =mans
[4] =wars
[5] =rody
[6] =low
[7] =high
)
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    print '<a href="https://example.com/'.$tagsfinal[$i].'" class="ivkeys">' . $tagsfinal[$i] . '</a>';
}
```

**i want this : **

```
 out=<a href="https://example.com/say" class="ivkeys">
 <a href="https://example.com/hello" class="ivkeys">
 <a href="https://example.com/nice" class="ivkeys">
 <a href="https://example.com/mans" class="ivkeys">
 <a href="https://example.com/wars" class="ivkeys">
```

Anyone know of a good alternative or better way to write this code?

thanks for your helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with loop foreach**

Iterate all the array and print only the values before key `$printlimit`. `$tk` is the key, and `$tv` is the value, of each element.

```
$printlimit = 5;
foreach ($tagsfinal as $tk => $tv)
{
    if ($tk < $printlimit)
    {
        print '<a href="https://example.com/'.$tv.'" class="ivkeys">' . $tv . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: your solutions not work just   `for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
        print '<a href="https://example.com/'.$tagsfinal[$i].'" class="ivkeys">' . $tagsfinal[$i] . '</a>';
    }` work currently !

Comment: See my question again ! UPDATED